# Tabulator field - Show Different Value

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I would like to display field value as character, but underlying data as number, so when i do search query, i am able to utilize numeric data, instead of displayed data.

example

```
 { title: 'Plant' , field: 'plant.name'},
```

But required

```
{ title: 'Plant' , field [ex: search-column]: 'plant.id' , field [ex: display]:'plant.name' },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahhh. coming back to tabulator after long time, it totally skipped my mind .

here is the solution

```
{ title: 'Plant' , field: 'plant.id', 
   formatter:function(cell){
       // This is eager loaded data in Laravel
       return cell.getRow().getData().plant.title;
   }
},
```

Now , in you query, you can search relationship with

```
->orWhereHas('plant', function($q) use($request){
     $q->where('title','LIKE',"%$request->search%");
})
```

I hope this helps out others as well